# restful con claves foraneas

Tags: java, json, netbeans, glassfish, restful

Estoy haciendo el proyecto final y tengo un servico web restful creado en Netbeans que utiliza una base de datos remota a un servidor Glassfish. Tenemos que crear dos apps una escritorio y la otra Android en las que se pueda manipular/consultar en esta base de datos. Entre las tablas de la base de datos hay relaciones, claves foraneas. Cuando recupero, con get y en formato json, la tabla incidencias que tiene 5 claves foraneas, me arrastra todos los campos de dichas tablas. Y yo solo quiero los id de esos registros.

La clase persistente es esta:

```
package entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import utils.Views;

/**
 * Classe persistent
 * @author Montse Camps
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "incidencies")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findById", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findByDataIncidencia", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.dataIncidencia = :dataIncidencia")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findByDataInici", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.dataInici = :dataInici")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findByDataFi", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.dataFi = :dataFi")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findByDescCurta", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.descCurta = :descCurta")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Incidencies.findByDescLlarga", query = "SELECT i FROM Incidencies i WHERE i.descLlarga = :descLlarga")})
public class Incidencies implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "data_incidencia")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataIncidencia;

    @Column(name = "data_inici")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataInici;

    @Column(name = "data_fi")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataFi;

    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "desc_curta")
    private String descCurta;

    @Size(max = 300)
    @Column(name = "desc_llarga")
    private String descLlarga;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idIncidencia")
    private Collection<Notes> notesCollection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idIncidencia")
    private Collection<Imatges> imatgesCollection;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estat", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Estats idEstat;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_localitzacio", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Localitzacions idLocalitzacio;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_prioritat", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Prioritat idPrioritat;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuari_obertura", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuari idUsuariObertura;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuari_operari", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuari idUsuariOperari;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idIncidencia")
    private Collection<MaterialIncidencies> materialIncidenciesCollection;

    public Incidencies() {
    }

    public Incidencies(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDataIncidencia() {
        return dataIncidencia;
    }

    public void setDataIncidencia(Date dataIncidencia) {
        this.dataIncidencia = dataIncidencia;
    }

    public Date getDataInici() {
        return dataInici;
    }

    public void setDataInici(Date dataInici) {
        this.dataInici = dataInici;
    }

    public Date getDataFi() {
        return dataFi;
    }

    public void setDataFi(Date dataFi) {
        this.dataFi = dataFi;
    }

    public String getDescCurta() {
        return descCurta;
    }

    public void setDescCurta(String descCurta) {
        this.descCurta = descCurta;
    }

    public String getDescLlarga() {
        return descLlarga;
    }

    public void setDescLlarga(String descLlarga) {
        this.descLlarga = descLlarga;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Notes> getNotesCollection() {
        return notesCollection;
    }

    public void setNotesCollection(Collection<Notes> notesCollection) {
        this.notesCollection = notesCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Imatges> getImatgesCollection() {
        return imatgesCollection;
    }

    public void setImatgesCollection(Collection<Imatges> imatgesCollection) {
        this.imatgesCollection = imatgesCollection;
    }

    public Estats getIdEstat() {
        return idEstat;
    }

    public void setIdEstat(Estats idEstat) {
        this.idEstat = idEstat;
    }

    public Localitzacions getIdLocalitzacio() {
        return idLocalitzacio;
    }

    public void setIdLocalitzacio(Localitzacions idLocalitzacio) {
        this.idLocalitzacio = idLocalitzacio;
    }

    public Prioritat getIdPrioritat() {
        return idPrioritat;
    }

    public void setIdPrioritat(Prioritat idPrioritat) {
        this.idPrioritat = idPrioritat;
    }

    public Usuari getIdUsuariObertura() {
        return idUsuariObertura;
    }

    public void setIdUsuariObertura(Usuari idUsuariObertura) {
        this.idUsuariObertura = idUsuariObertura;
    }

    public Usuari getIdUsuariOperari() {
        return idUsuariOperari;
    }

    public void setIdUsuariOperari(Usuari idUsuariOperari) {
        this.idUsuariOperari = idUsuariOperari;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<MaterialIncidencies> getMaterialIncidenciesCollection() {
        return materialIncidenciesCollection;
    }

    public void setMaterialIncidenciesCollection(Collection<MaterialIncidencies> materialIncidenciesCollection) {
        this.materialIncidenciesCollection = materialIncidenciesCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Incidencies)) {
            return false;
        }
        Incidencies other = (Incidencies) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: "+id+", id_localitzacio: "+idLocalitzacio.getId()+", id_usuari_obertura: "+idUsuariObertura.getId()+", id_usuari_operari: "+idUsuariOperari.getId()+
                ", id_estat: "+idEstat.getId()+", id_prioritat: "+idPrioritat.getId()+", data_incidencia: "+dataIncidencia.toString()+", data_inici: "+dataInici.toString()+
                ", data_fi: "+dataFi.toString()+", desc_curta: "+descCurta+", desc_llarga: "+descLlarga+"; ";
    }

}
```

Y el metodo get que viene por defecto al crear el servicio es este:

```
@GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Incidencies> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }
```

Y cuando hago el get, el json me sale asi:

```
{
    "dataFi": "2017-04-06T00:00:00+02:00",
    "dataIncidencia": "2017-03-25T00:00:00+01:00",
    "dataInici": "2017-04-06T00:00:00+02:00",
    "descCurta": "Aixeta trencada",
    "descLlarga": "La aixeta del lavabo situat a la dreta està bessant aigua continuament",
    "id": 1,
    "idEstat": {
      "id": 2,
      "nomEstat": "assignada"
    },
    "idLocalitzacio": {
      "id": 12,
      "nomLloc": "dpt. exportació"
    },
    "idPrioritat": {
      "id": 2,
      "nomPrioritat": "normal"
    },
    "idUsuariObertura": {
      "bloquejat": false,
      "cognoms": "Olivera Cortes",
      "contrasenya": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
      "correu": "EulaliaOli@gmail.com",
      "id": 2,
      "idTipus": {
        "id": 2,
        "nomTipus": "gestor"
      },
      "idUsuari": "EulaliaOli2",
      "mobil": "698899663",
      "nom": "Calatina"
    },
    "idUsuariOperari": {
      "bloquejat": false,
      "cognoms": "Olivera Cortes",
      "contrasenya": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
      "correu": "EulaliaOli@gmail.com",
      "id": 3,
      "idTipus": {
        "id": 2,
        "nomTipus": "gestor"
      },
      "idUsuari": "EulaliaOli",
      "mobil": "698899663",
      "nom": "Eulalia"
    }
  },
```

Y yo quiero que me salga asi:

```
{
    "dataFi": "2017-04-06T00:00:00+02:00",
    "dataIncidencia": "2017-03-25T00:00:00+01:00",
    "dataInici": "2017-04-06T00:00:00+02:00",
    "descCurta": "Aixeta trencada",
    "descLlarga": "La aixeta del lavabo situat a la dreta està bessant aigua continuament",
    "id": 1,
    "idEstat":2,
    "idLocalitzacio": 12 ,   
    "idPrioritat": 2,
    "idUsuariObertura": 2,
    "idUsuariOperari": 2,
  }
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?
Lógicamente con esta estructura también tengo problemas con el post y el put.

Otra opción seria que desde la aplicación se pueda leer el json con Java (es el lenguaje que utilizamos) descartando los campos de las llaves foráneas que no interesen y quedarse con el id de la llave foránea solo. Pero como? No encuentro soluciones en ninguna parte.

Comment: Hay anotaciones que te permiten no recuperar todo buscar lazy column en tu Framework de persistencia

Comment: Si, ya se a que te refieres @programmercito. Lo estuve probando también y no me funcionó, Quizás no lo hice bien. Finalmente lo he solucionado con el método **toString()**. No es la mejor solución pero así no tengo a mis compañeros esperando. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hablo sin saber muy bien como se hace:

No hagas JoinColumn.
Declara los tipos basicos:

```
@Column(name = "id_stat")
int idEstat;
```

El JSON que quieres funcionara.
Supongo que otras cositas dejaran de funcionar...

Otra posible solución:

Nueva clase Incidencies2 que contenga los campos basicos como he dicho arriba, y un metodo que convierta de Incidencies a Incidencies2.

Y luego Incidencies2 es lo que convierto a JSON y devuelvo.

Comment: Gracias Angel pero si quito el JoinColumn me dejan de funcionar otras partes del código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal en estos casos es tener un Java Bean, un Data Transfer Object (DTO) para la capa de *presentación* (aunque sea un servicio REST), sigue considerándose capa de presentación:

```
class IncidenciesDTO {

   // los campos de Incidencies que quieras enviar

   static public IncidenciesDTO populateDTO(Incidencies in) {
       IncidenciesDTO dto= new IncidenciesDTO();
       dto.id=in.getId();
       // ... resto de campos 

       return dto;
   }
}
```

Por lo que tu servicio quedaría algo como:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<IncidenciesDTO> findAll() {
    List<IncidenciesDTO> dtoList = super.findAll().stream()
        .map(in -> IncidenciesDTO.populateDTO(in)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return dtoList;
}
```